# How can i Merge/Summaries two JSON array into one based on one key variable in R?

Tags: r, json, dplyr, jsonlite, plumber

> I have some JSON arrays as -
>
> "expenseRecords": [
>    {
>     "date_expensed": "2019-04-01",
>     "exp_cat_description": "Air Travel",
>     "totalamountUSD": 10,
>     "totalRecords": 2
>     },
>     {
>     "date_expensed": "2019-04-01",
>      "exp_cat_description": "Breakfast",
>      "totalamountUSD": 11,
>      "totalRecords": 1
>     }]
>
> And my desired format is 
>   "expenseRecords": [
>    {
>     "date_expensed": "2019-04-01",{
>     "exp_cat_description": "Air Travel",
>     "totalamountUSD": 10,
>     "totalRecords": 2 
>     },
>     {
>     "exp_cat_description": "Breakfast",
>      "totalamountUSD": 11,
>      "totalRecords": 1
>     }, ]
>
> How to achieve this in R

Answer (score 0):

```
let newarray =[]

const object1 = {
  name: 'Flavio'
}

const object2 = {
  age: 35
}

const object3 = {...object1, ...object2 }
newArray=[...newArray,object3]
```

Comment: Please always take some time to add an explanation to your answer, this will improve your answer also for future users. Tnx

Comment: click the arrow up if the answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jsonlite library and the split data.frame fonction.

First convert your json to an R object than split the data.frame by the variable and then rewrite the json object.

```r
inputjson <- '{"expenseRecords": [ { "date_expensed": "2019-04-01", "exp_cat_description": "Air Travel", "totalamountUSD": 10, "totalRecords": 2 }, { "date_expensed": "2019-04-01", "exp_cat_description": "Breakfast", "totalamountUSD": 11, "totalRecords": 1 },{ "date_expensed": "2019-04-02", "exp_cat_description": "Air Travel", "totalamountUSD": 10, "totalRecords": 2 }]}'

library(jsonlite)

input <- fromJSON(inputjson)

input$expenseRecords <- split(input$expenseRecords[,-1], input$expenseRecords$date_expensed)

output <- toJSON(input)
```